# C++ classes and vectors

Tags: c++, class, pointers, vector

I am confused by this! I keep getting the error message that:

> `addSchool` is not declared in the scope

and,

> no matching function for call to `school::addschool()`

I can't see how these aren't declared. (I am also new to programming)

`School` is a class and one of the members of this class is a vector pointer.

`.h` File:

```
class school {
private:
    vector<school*> schools;

public:
    school();
    void addSchool(school *s);
};
```

`.cpp` file:

```
void school::addSchool(school *s){
    vector<school *> schools;
    s = new school();
    schools.push_back(s);
}
```

`main` function:

```
school *newSchool = new school();
school::addSchool(&newSchool);
delete newSchool;
```

Comment: `newSchool ` is a pointer, so `&newSchool` is a pointer-to-pointer.

Comment: And none of this stands a chance of compiling; `addSchool` is neither a static class member nor takes a `school **` argument, both would break compilation with one single line from the call in `main`. Also, though not a compile-time error, the local `schools` object in `school::addSchool` hides the member variable `schools`, making that a flat logic bug.

Comment: `newSchool` is a value that lives on the stack, and any attempt to store its address will result in `oldSchool` if used after that stack is torn down.

Comment: Why are you using "HEADER FILE" and "CPP file" and "MAIN FUNCTION" at the code level. Please just cut and paste your code. There seems to be some missing parts.

Answer (score 0):

**A few issues here**:

- Calling a non-static member function as if it were a static function. Change the function prototype to this:

  `static void addSchool(school *s);`
- Passing a pointer to pointer to `school` in the function `addSchool` which takes only a pointer to `school`. Change the function call to this:

  `school::addSchool(newSchool);`
- Declaring a local `vector` of `schools` in the `addSchool` function instead of using the already available `private` member `vector<school *> schools`. This will add only to the local `vector` of `schools` and not to the member `vector` of `schools`. Remove the following line in the `addSchool` function

  `vector<school *> schools;`
- Allocating memory for `school` again in the `addSchool` function. This will cause a memory leak. You have to allocate memory only once. If you want to do it in `main`, remove the following line in the `addSchool` function.

  `s = new school();`
- Deleting the memory allocated in `main` should be done only at the end of the program. Otherwise, you will be left hanging with a `vector` of pointers that are not valid.

**I think that:**

- The `vector` of `schools` should also be a `static` because it is not specific to a particular instantiation. In that case, change the declaration of `vector` of `schools` to this:

  `static vector<school *> schools;`

See **[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/91cbf66715d5898f)**

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be 2 main problems here. The error you are getting is in how you are calling `addSchool()`. You are using the syntax to call a static function when you have it declared as a member. To call it as a member:

```
school.addSchool(newSchool);
```

Note using the `.` instead of `::`, but also that newSchool is already a pointer so don't take the address of it. (As others already pointed out)

The other problems are run time errors in your addSchool method. You are creating a local vector, not using the member. You are also ignoring the parameter sent.

```
void school::addSchool(school *s) {
    for( i=0; i < s->size(); i++) {
        this.schools.push_back(s[i]);
    }
}
```

Now that I write that out, I realize there is also a bigger logical problem here in what this class actually is supposed to be. Its a school that contains a list of schools, so are you adding a school to that list or combining lists? While such things make sense for link lists and trees, your example says "schools" so I would rethink it. Perhaps your class should be a school district to contain a list of schools:

```
class District{
private:
    vector<school *> schools; // school declared elsewhere
public:
    District();
    inline int Size() { return this.schools.size(); };
    inline int Get(int i) { return this.schools[i]; };
    void addSchool(school *s);
    void addSchools(District *d);
}

// adding to the list
void District::addSchool(school *s) {
    this.schools.push_back(s);
}

// adding the contents of another like class, consider operator overloading + instead
void District::addSchools(District *d) {
    for( i=0; i < d->Size(); i++) {
        this.schools.push_back( d->Get(i) );
    }
}
```

Alternately, if you want a single static function as a master list, lookup the [Singleton design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/1933695).